# Testing methods inside Service

Tags: java, testing, junit, service

I am building webapplication in MVCS structure.

I got all methods with logic inside Service class.

How i can test it using junit? Can some one explain to me how should it work? Or give a course / article? I tried alot of resources, but non of them cover my case.

I am also open for sugestion, maybe my design is bad here...

When I am makeing methods public static it works, however I am not sure if that should be the case.

When I am trying to `@Autowire` service field I am getting NullPointerException :(

```java
@Service
public class MapValueServiceImpl implements MapValueService {

    methodThatDoesSomething() {
    }
}
```

```java
class MapValueServiceImplTest {

    @Test
    public void TestingMethodThatDoesSomething() {
      assertEquals(Something, methodThatDoesSomething())
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` (or similar) to run your test class? You need Spring to handle `@Autowired`, and if it's `null`, then most likely you're using the default runner which doesn't know anything about Spring or `@Autowired`.

Comment: I think it's better if you post your code that is failing instead of pseudo-code.

Comment: If you're just unit testing you might want to consider a mocking framework (like Mockito). Then your mocked autowired dependencies will be injected in.

Comment: Yes. The thing is i dont want to mock dependencies. I want to test method in the dependency :)

Answer (score 0):

For test MVC I can recommend you this tutorial from Spring

https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

you can check other tutorials in this site. I hope it's help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example service:

```
@Service
public class MapValueServiceImpl implements MapValueService {

    @Autowired private GreetingService greetingService;

    String getGreeting(String name) {
        return greetingService.buildGreeting(name);
    }
}
```

If you bring in mockito (assuming you're using Maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you can do something like this...

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MapValueServiceImplTest {

    @Mock private GreetingService greetingService; // <-- define your mocks
    @InjectMocks private MapValueServiceImpl toTest; // <-- your mocks will be injected

    // Now you can test dependency interaction...

    @Test
    public void whenNamePassedThenCorrectGreetingReturned() { 
        // Arrange
        final String name = "George";
        final String greeting = "Hello " + name;
        doReturn(greeting).when(greetingService).buildGreeting(name);

        // Act
        final String result = toTest.getGreeting(name);

        // Assert
        assertThat(result, is(greeting));
    }

}
```

This is a pure unit test (and does not require a Spring context). You can find more information on Mockito here: https://site.mockito.org/